# Casting "number 0" to char before appending it

Tags: c++, string, casting, explicit

Why would I need to explicitly cast `number 0` to `char` before appending it to string using `string::operator+`?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string s = "";
    s += 65; // no compile error
    s += (char)0; // requires explicit cast 
    //s += 0; // compile error
    return 0;
}
```

**Update to clarify**: My goal has been to append one byte (containing whatever value, including zero) to an existing array of bytes.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you wish to have a simple string "A", i.e. one real character in it? If so, then you should edit and clarify the question. If your string is printed, do you expect to see "A" or "A0"? Also, check out my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `s += 0` is ambiguous for the following overloaded operators of +=

```
string& operator+= ( const char* s );
string& operator+= ( char c );
```

`0` for the first function means a NULL terminated string with first character set to NULL, and for the second function is a single character with value set to `0`.

Comment: Actually, passing zero for the first means a NULL *pointer*, not a NULL-terminated string length zero. There's a difference: a NULL-terminated string of length zero is a string, while a NULL pointer is not a string at all. You can do `thing[0]` to the NULL-terminated string and get an answer (namely 0); doing that to a NULL pointer kills your app.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas It's undefined behavior. It doesn't have to crash your app.

Comment: I think most people here have misunderstood. What is the goal of the original question? Is it to append the digit `'0'` to the string to give "A0"? Or is it to ensure that they have a properly terminated string "A" of length 1? In either case, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Neither of what you said has been my goal. I didn't want to construct a printable string. 65 was just an example, which could be any value between 0 and 255.

Comment: Hi @Meysam, many of the characters between 0 and 255 are unprintable. There is a function called [isprint](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isprint/) that tells whether a character is printable. And `\0` is not printable, according to that function. 65 is the code for `'A'`.

Answer (score 7):

It is because ONLY `0` can be *implicitly* converted into pointer type. No other integer can *implicitly* be converted into pointer type. In your case, `0` can be converted into `const char*` and `char` both. When it is converted into `const char*`, it becomes a null pointer.

So there is ambiguity as to which conversion should take place, as there are two overloads of `operator+=`, for each type  of arguments: `const char*` and `char`.

But when you use non-zero integer, say `65`, it cannot convert into `const char*`. So the only function it can call is one which takes `char` as argument, as `65` is converted into `char`.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler views `s += 0;` as an ambiguous call.  It sees both `operator+=(char*)` and `operator+=(char)` as valid calls.

As all the other replies have said, `std::string` has no way of appending an integer.  However, this answer doesn't really address your question, as you append the integer `65` in one line, and this does not cause you an error.

First, this seems like a non-conformity in your C++ implementation; this *should not work*.  But, given that it does, why does appending `0` fail?  The reason is that C++ compilers regard the literal `0` as either an integer or the null pointer, depending on context.  (C++11 added `nullptr` and friends to <strike>add to</strike> alleviate this source of confusion.)

Therefore, when your implementation sees the line

```
s += 0;
```

it cannot decide between calling `operator+=(char*)` and `operator+=(char)`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [C++ string reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).  The following overloads are defined:

```
string& operator+= ( const string& str );
string& operator+= ( const char* s );
string& operator+= ( char c );
```

To make C++ understand what you want to do, you need to append something whose type matches one of these signatures..

Comment: "_you need to append something whose type matches one of these signatures.._" `0` match all three!

Answer (score 1):

What everybody told you is that `0` is an `int`, that the availabe `operator+=()` takes a `char` or a `char*`, that 0 (but no other integers) can be converted to both and so there is an ambiguity.

What everybody forgot to tell you is that the correct idiom isn't a cast but to use a `char` litteral

```
s += '\0';
```

Comment: I don't see any "correct idiom" behind this:

(char)0
char(0)
'\0'

are all equivalent syntax for 8 zero filled bits.

Comment: C cast are banned by all C++ style guide I'm aware, and they all want to restrict the casts to the places they are needed.  There is a syntax for char in C++, using casts instead isn't something which will pass any code review I've assisted.

Comment: "C cast are banned by all C++ style guide I'm aware" Style guides are *guides*, not *religion*. char(0) is not a cast, is a creation of a temporary value. (char)0 is a cast. I can understand the guide reason, but in this context the problem is soooo trivial that referring to a "style guide" is overkill.

Comment: @AProgrammer "_C cast are banned by all C++ style guide I'm aware_" Then all C++ style guide you are aware of are really inane.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia "`char(0)` _is not a cast_" Of course it is a cast! "_is a creation of a temporary value._" Wrong. "`(char)0` _is a cast._" just as `char(0)`.

Comment: @curiousguy: oh, well ... being char a built-in type this is more a sophism then else, but...

`char(0)` is not different (in syntax) than `point(0,0)`. 
I think anyone will recognize a invocation of a constructor creating a temporary of `class point`, in the last case.
You can even call `char()` to get a *default initialized `char`* that result in a null character.

The idiom between char(0) is the same that -for objects- gives an explicit invocation of a ctor, that can be used implicitly in conversion (since it takes one parameter) but cannot be technically called *cast*.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia "_char(0) is not different (in syntax) than point(0,0)_" It is different: `char(0)` **is** a cast. `point(0,0)` is **not** a cast. That's the difference. "_but cannot be technically called cast._" Hug? Then how do you call it: an uncast?

Comment: "_char(0) is not a cast, is a creation of a temporary value._" `char(0)` yields a value; it doesn't "create a temporary value". Values are the result of some expression; they don't have lifetime, and "temporary" is meaningless here.

Comment: @curiousguy: *char(0) is a cast. point(0,0) is not a cast. That's the difference.*

It doesn't matter. I can do nothing against religion!
Be happy with your god, and let me be happy with mine. Until we get the same results, nobody will care! (Nobody but Taliban, of course!)

Comment: My God is called the C++ programming language. `(Type) expression` is called a "C-style cast" by my God and `Type (expression)` is a called a "new-style cast" (not so new now) or rather a "functional cast".

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have a string equal to "A", then you should simply do:

```
string s = "";
s += 65;
```

In C++, you do not need to put a null character (`0` or `'\0'` or `'0'` or anything like that) on the end of strings. In fact, you must not do this. This is different from C, where you do often need to think carefully about this.

What is your goal? If you don't want a simple "A" as your string, perhaps you want "A0", in which case you would do `string s = "";s += 65;s += '0';return 0;`

Comment: To expand: In the code in the question, the string will have length 2, but when you print it to your terminal, it will look simply like `A`. This is misleading. In summary, only put printable characters (i.e. not `\0`) into your C++ strings.

Answer (score -2):

`string` represents characters. `0` represents an integer. You must type cast to a char to be compatible.

Note that `'0'` would be a character, and would not need a cast.

Comment: Note that `'0'` is not the same as `(char)0`

Comment: @Seth: I never thought or suggested they were the same! I was only clarifying that case, in the event the OP did not realize they were different!

Comment: Yes, I didn't suggest that you were suggesting they were the same, I was just clarifying a potential ambiguity. I didn't downvote this answer.